# How to change language used in a project from Kotlin to Java

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

How to change  language used in a project from Kotlin to Java in android studio 
and 
what if i change the .ktto .java in directory

Comment: i didnt start codig yet i got the problem when i first tried to build the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

you can choose from start java or kotlin

Comment: thanks  i was wondring if i could change it back to java after starting the project

Comment: it can be android studio can be work both of them you can write aclass with kotlin and other with java

Comment: if its a answer can you mark my answer tick for the answer